# Why isnt netbeans letting me use lambda expressions on dragged and dropped buttons in GUI

Tags: java, swing, lambda, netbeans

For some reason, it is not letting me use lambda expressions instead of

```
private void btn_addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
}
```

How do I implement lambda expressions in netbeans on buttons which were dragged and dropped on the GUI. I want the lambda expression to act as a MouseClick event handler

I tried right clicking on button on the gui and selecting actionPerformed and then try deleting actionPerformed in the code but it doesnt let me delete the method. MY plan was to do this and then replace it with

```
btn_Add.addActionListener((event) -> {
    
});
```

But it doesnt let me delete. Even if I go to events sections in properties and remove the event. It still doesnt work adn shows an error when I type the lambda expression. This is a swing project.I have to submit the project tommorow. Any help regarding this would mean a lot.

Comment: *I have to submit the project tommorow* - not relevant to the question. My advice is to NOT use the IDE to generate code because you spend time learning the IDE and not Java/Swing. Write the code yourself and just use the IDE to help compile, debug etc.

Comment: Code completion offers both and lets you switch; see Help > Keyboard Shortcuts.